# Discarding a single attribute in R

Tags: r, missing-data

In R, the `na.omit()` function can be used to discard entries in a data.frame that contain NA values. As a side effect, if lines are indeed discarded, the function adds an attribute 'omit' to the result that contains a vector of the row.names that were discarded.

I want to discard this 'omit' attribute because I don't need it. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Or don't use na.omit. This isnt really what it's for anyway.

Comment: Hadley, your comment is confusing me.  If na.omit is not really for discarding rows with NA from a data.frame, then what is it really for?

Comment: I'm also a little confused as to what @Hadley is recommending using here. I know there you could do purrr::discard(x, is.na) but not sure what the "correct" Base R function (as usually have used na.omit() or na.exclude() )... Anyone know what the right way to do this with Base R is though...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use `data.frame` after `na.omit` or you can do it directly:

```
> temp <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,44),b=c(99,29,NA))
> new <- na.omit(temp)
> attributes(new)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
[1] 1

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$na.action
2 3
2 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

> reduced <- data.frame(new)
> attributes(reduced)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
[1] 1

$class
[1] "data.frame"
>
```

direct method:

```
attributes(new)$na.action <- NULL
```